# Enable progress bar on current row only

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a progress bar, however if I change progress to an ID, all other lines are affected.
How can I change the progress only on that line without changing the rest?

**html**

```
    <div class="progress aqua" [attr.data-width]="percentage" (mousedown)="startUpdateSlider(data)"
        (mouseup)="endUpdateSlider(data)" (mouseleave)="endUpdateSlider(data)" (mousemove)="updateSlider($event,data)">
        <div class="progress-text">{{progress}}</div>
        <div class="progress-bar" [style.width]="percentage">
            <div class="progress-text">{{progress}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Component.ts**

```
 startUpdateSlider(data) {
    this.currentID = data.key.id;
    this.updateSliderToggle = true;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change style binding as follows,

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jichpb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```html
<div class="progress-bar" [style.width]="data.key.progress + '%'">
```

And in your update function, you don't need class level `percentage` variable.

**Component**

```js
 updateSlider(event, data) {

    if (this.updateSliderToggle) {
      this.currentID = data.key.id;
      let percentage: number = Math.floor(
        (event.layerX / (event.target.offsetWidth - 3)) * 100
      );

      if (percentage > 100) {
        percentage = 100;
      } else if (percentage < 0) {
        percentage = 0;
      }
      data.key.progress = percentage;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace ([style.width])

```
<div class="progress-bar" [style.width]="percentage">
  <div class="progress-text">{{data.key.progress}}</div>
</div>
```

with

```
<div class="progress-bar" [style.width]="data.key.progress + '%">
  <div class="progress-text">{{data.key.progress}}</div>
</div>
```